# Xpath3 - Get name from SOAP message

Tags: xml, xpath, soap, xpath-3.0

This is my `SOAP message` and I want to get the name of the child element of **soap:Body**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/" xmlns:pref="URI_SOAP_WS">
   <soap:Body>
      <pref:book>
         <pref:author>Gambardella, Matthew</pref:author>
         <pref:title>XML Developer's Guide</pref:title>
         <pref:genre>Computer</pref:genre>
         <pref:price>44.95</pref:price>
         <pref:publish_date>2000-10-01</pref:publish_date>
         <pref:description>An in-depth look XML</pref:description>
      </pref:book>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

How can I get the name of `<pref:book>`?

I want to use for comparison in a switch.

Comment: By *the name* of `<pref:book>`, do you mean to get a string `"perf:book"`?

Comment: @har07 Yes, I want to get the String `"perf:book"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to get element name of direct child of `<soap:Body>`, so in this case it means a string `"pref:book"`, you can try this way :

```
declare namespace soap = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/";
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*/name()
```

Output will be `pref:book`, exactly as needed. Tested using XPath 2.0 here : http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi

Comment: Thanks ! I needed to add the namespace.